# Multiple AFHTTPClient Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afhttpclient

I've got subclass of `AFHTTPClient`
The main idea is that i call all API through my singleton of `AFHTTPClient` subclass, and all requests goes through 1 points for error handling and HUD displaying.
This is entry point for every API calls:

```
-(void) makeRequestWithPath:(NSString*) path andParams:(NSDictionary*) params 
                    success:(void (^)( id JSON, AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation)) success
                    failure:(void (^)( NSError *error)) failure
```

And i've got many methods for API calls something like that:

```
-(void) getListMainTreeWithSuccess:(void (^)( id JSON, AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation)) success
                       failure:(void (^)( NSError *error)) failure
{

[self makeRequestWithPath:@"objects/selectlist" andParams:nil success:^(id JSON, AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation) {
    success(JSON,operation);
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    failure(error);
}];

}
```

This works just fine for my needs. But i faced problem that i need to make serial request in loop through my `AFHTTPClient` subclass and make some action when all of them are finished , I found method

```
-(void)enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:(NSArray *)urlRequests
                                      progressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations))progressBlock
                                    completionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *operations))completionBlock
```

which should solve my issue, but the problem is that i call all methods through `AFHTTPClient` and it's methods getPath: and postPath: and previous way forces me to rewrite everything and makes my subclass completely useless, because I need to add there `NSArray` of `AFHTTPRequestoperation`, which is not possible to construct or extract from my subclass and my methods. Previously i tried to use __block 's to synchronise requests with semaphore and something else but i failed to get what i need, please help me!

***UPDATE:***
It seems that it is not possible to even use `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations` method (even with rewriting all my code) because this method needs array of http request operations, but it's not possible to construct POST request with them.

Comment: You can POST with `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with an increment/decrement pending download system and tied the HUD to that.

```
[networkStatus beginNetworkActivity];
[client someRESTActionWithCompletion:^(id object, NSError *error) {
    [networkStatus endNetworkActivity];

    if (error) {
        // Handle the error ...
    }

    if (![networkStatus hasNetworkActivity]) {
        // All downloads have finished
    }
}];
```

I keep the network status object separate which from the AFHTTPClient subclass, but it can be built into the client if that's what you want.

Network status keeps an internal counter. `-beginNetworkActivity` increments the counter, if the counter was 0, then it displays a HUD. `-endNetworkActivity` decrements the counter, if the counter becomes 0, then it dismisses the HUD. `-hasNetworkActivity` returns `YES` if the counter greater than 0.

Other Notes: I combine the success and failed callbacks into a [single completion callback](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184597/success-failure-blocks-vs-completion-block). I keep the network status logic separate from the client because sometime I'll use a singleton network status object, sometimes I'll use a created instance, sometimes I won't use one at all. It all depends on the needs to the higher level logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i don't have problem displaying HUD, i've already realised it in my subclass of AFHTTPClient. I've got a problem  executing many request through AFHTTPClient in one place and so that i know when exactly ALL of them are finished so i can execute further code. With ASIHTTP it was easy because all the answers were going to one single method, and all of the request was executing one after another, so i exactly knew when all of them are finished.

Comment: @KysokZla `[networkStatus hasNetworkActivity]` would return NO when all requests have finished. It is the indicator you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Again, as @MikePollard said, create `AFHTTPRequestOperation` using

```
[AFHHTPClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:]
```

For this method create `NSURLRequest` using (or use another one, pick which one is suitable for you). Here you can also specify, which method to use `POST`, `GET` or any other.

```
[AFHTTPClient requestWithMethod:
                           path:
                     parameters:]
```

After that save all operation to an `NSArray`, and schedule them using:

```
[AFHTTPClient enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:
                                                progressBlock:
                                              completionBlock:]
```

**Code example:**

```
NSMutableArray *ops = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [[AFHTTPClient sharedClient] requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                                          path:@"MyEndpoint"
                                                                    parameters:@{@"key1": @"value"}];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op1 = [[AFHTTPClient sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request1
                                                                                   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                                                       NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                                                   }
                                                                                   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                                       NSLog(@"Failure!");
                                                                                   }];
[ops addObject:op1];

NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [[AFHTTPClient sharedClient] requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                          path:@"MyAnotherEndpoint"
                                                                    parameters:@{@"key2": @(104)}];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op2 = [[AFHTTPClient sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request2
                                                                                   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                                                       NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                                                   }
                                                                                   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                                       NSLog(@"Failure!");
                                                                                   }];
[ops addObject:op2];
[[AFHTTPClient sharedClient] enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:ops
                                                               progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
                                                                   NSLog(@"numberOfFinishedOperations: %d totalNumberOfOperations %d",
                                                                         numberOfFinishedOperations,
                                                                         totalNumberOfOperations);
                                                               }
                                                             completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
                                                                 NSLog(@"All operation compelted!");
                                                             }];
```

Comment: Sorry, i can't understand your answer( Could u provide a simple code, with, for example, 2 different POST request with 2 different params for each and executing them with ur approach. Would appreciate your help very much

Comment: Exactly i'm not getting how is it possible to save HTTPRequestOperation object through    [AFHHTPClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:]   because this object is only available in success block, and this block only comes up when operation is finished. Am i wrong somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you're missing something there, it is always good practice to take a look to documentation or header file.
But anyway, I have added an example, I hope now you will understand the idea.

Comment: Good to know, there is a mistake in your example:

`enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests` takes an array of NSURLRequest.

`enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations` actually takes an array of AFHTTPRequestOperation. You're mixing the both in your code, it's not gonna work.